# How to create a "tail" on a chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a tail on a chrome extension popup, pointing to the extension icon, as show here:

[image: popup with tail from extension docs]

I tried reviewing the docs, including where the above image came from, but cannot find anything. See image at this link:

[Extension doc showing tail in popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

Comment: ahh, popups are just html pages. Even, I am not sure hot to do it but maybe in your .html file for the popup, you can design it such that tail shows and then your pop. 

Also, as always, you can always inspect the chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't

The screenshot you provided is from an older version of chromium, where that "tail" was part of the UI. Maybe there is a css hack to achieve what you want, but like I said, they removed the tail at some point from the chromium UI, so I wouldn't waste time working on it.

Comment: There's no CSS hack either, the popup's border is drawn in C++ code natively.